# Set RelativeLayout.LayoutParams programmatically

Tags: xamarin.android

I have this ScrollView:

```
<Scrollview
    android:id="@+id/DashboardView_menuContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fillViewport="true" />
```

I have since realised I need to give it a dynamic height which means I need to do the layout for it programmatically.

This is what I have so far:

```
_menuContainer = FindViewById < ViewGroup > (Resource.Id.DashboardView_menuContainer);

//get height of screen
var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
var menuWidth = metrics.WidthPixels;
var menuHeight = metrics.HeightPixels - 200;

//TODO: add anchorBottom to the layoutParams
_menuContainer.LayoutParameters = (new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(menuWidth, menuHeight));
```

So I just need to add the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` programmatically to the layour params. I'm unsure how to add anything to the layoutParams except for width and height. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(menuWidth, menuHeight);
parameters.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentBottom);
_menuContainer.LayoutParameters = parameters;
```

Comment: its giving the exception Java.Lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: You got this exception because you are trying to add RelativeLayout parameters to a LinearLayout object (_menuContainer in the above code). Be sure the layout you are trying to apply parameters on is a RelativeLayout, otherwise it won't work. If you need to keep it as a LinearLayout, use LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(menuWidth, menuHeight); but you won't be able to use AddRule as it is RelativeLayout specific.

Comment: no i am apply on relative layout object my menuContainer  is relative layout